# How to return whole JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I have this JSONFile

```
{"PostsDetails":[
  {
    "pageInfo": {
    "pagePic": "http://example.com/abc.jpg",
    "pageName": "abc"
    },
  "id": 1,
  "posts": [
    {
      "likesCount": "2",
      "nameOfPersonWhoPosted": "Jane Doe",
      "post_id": "0987654321_123456789012",
      "timeOfPost": "0987654321",
      "actor_id": "0987654321",
      "message": "Can't wait to see it!",
      "picOfPersonWhoPosted": "http://example.com/abc.jpg"
    }
   ]
 }
]}
```

And I have this method to search by post_id in posts array

```
public JSONArray getPostList(String post_id) {

   JSONObject jsonObject = JSONFileUtil2.getFileJSONObject();
   JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("PostsDetails");

   JSONArray returnArr = new JSONArray();
   for (Object aJsonArray : arr) {
       jsonObject = (JSONObject) aJsonArray;


       JSONArray postsArr = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("posts");
        for (Object bJsonArray : postsArr) {
            jsonObject= (JSONObject) bJsonArray;
             if (jsonObject.get("post_id").equals(post_id)) {
                 returnArr.add(jsonObject);
           }
        }
   }

   return returnArr;
}
```

But Im only getting a return value like this. I want to return the whole object including the id, pageInfo and posts object. How can I do that?

```
[
 {
   "likesCount": "2",
   "nameOfPersonWhoPosted": "Jane Doe",
   "post_id": "0987654321_123456789012",
   "timeOfPost": "0987654321",
   "actor_id": "0987654321",
   "message": "Can't wait to see it!",
   "picOfPersonWhoPosted": "http://example.com/abc.jpg"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to your found array json object by access to first for iteration object; you don't overwrite jsonObject to access your desire object:

```
   for (Object aJsonArray : arr) {
       JSONObject foundJsonObject = (JSONObject) aJsonArray;

       JSONArray postsArr = (JSONArray) foundJsonObject.get("posts");
        for (Object bJsonArray : postsArr) {
            JSONObject postJsonObject= (JSONObject) bJsonArray;
             if (postJsonObject.get("post_id").equals(post_id)) {
                 returnArr.add(foundJsonObject);
           }
        }
   }
```

but attention that your return obejct will be a JSONObject not JSONArray like this :

```
{
 {
    "pageInfo": {
    "pagePic": "http://example.com/abc.jpg",
    "pageName": "abc"
    },
  "id": 1,
  "posts": [
    {
      "likesCount": "2",
      "nameOfPersonWhoPosted": "Jane Doe",
      "post_id": "0987654321_123456789012",
      "timeOfPost": "0987654321",
      "actor_id": "0987654321",
      "message": "Can't wait to see it!",
      "picOfPersonWhoPosted": "http://example.com/abc.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code but Im getting "Duplicate local variable jsonObject".

Comment: I revise code to show only your solution, I correct code by rename new object which store "posts" attribute. now you can use code!

Comment: you can just use a regular for loop to avoid the overwriting you are getting

Comment: Thank you for your help but Im getting null value at line "for (Object bJsonArray : postsArr)".

Comment: I forget to refactor this line :
JSONArray postsArr = (JSONArray) foundJsonObject.get("posts");
now, it is corrected.

Comment: @M2E67 I got it now. But what if I have 2 results? Im only getting 1 result even if I have 2 result with same search value

Comment: You can check array before adding result to prevent adding duplicate result; for these it is better to define a class for mapping string to this class, then write a equal method for this class. in adding result, you can convert string to your object class and check for duplicate by using equal method.